# Hide a timer and make it appear when it reaches a certain value

Tags: jquery

I am using a timer plugin for Drupal CMS. The timer counts down and shows the user how long they have before they are automatically logged out.

The timer is in a div with a class of `logoutstatus`. The timer its self is wrapped in a `strong` tag.

The timer is annoying, so I only want it to appear when it counts down to 00:09:55. How do I do this?

I have tried the following code:

```
(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.logoutstatus').hide();

if ($('logoutstatus:contains("00:09:57")').length > 0) {
   $('.logoutstatus').show();
}

});

}(jQuery));
```

However, because the countdown is a dynamic element, the code doesn't seem to react to it. I would appreciate any pointers.  Thanks!

I know I should probably build the jQuery timer into my code. However, I have to use the Drupal one, so this isn't an option.

Comment: You have to periodically check whether the element contains the value. Depending on the frequency of the check you might have to perform some more sophisticated comparison than just a simple text comparison.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! How do I do this?

Comment: With `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout. Of course if you could hook into the timer somehow, that would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can I use setTimeout with my existing code or do I have to create a new timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your test is really working since you didn't post the relevant bits, however, assuming that the code is working, you just need to wrap it around a `setInterval` which will run every 1000ms. This should work, although, it'll add another useless timer.

As a side note, you are missing a `.` in your first selector.

Comment: This works perfectly! I want to extend my code by adding a class to the timer and adding a margin to the body. Here is the code I am using, but it doesn't work. I would appreciate any pointers:  `(function ($) {
 
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.logoutstatus').hide();
    

});

setInterval(function() {
     if ($('.logoutstatus:contains("00:09:56")').length > 0) {
   $('.logoutstatus').show().addclass('.fixedbox'),
   $('body').css("margin-top","72px")
}
 
}, 1000);


}(jQuery));
`

Comment: Try this: `$('.logoutstatus').show().addClass('fixedbox');$('body').css("margin-top","72px");`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the current timer value in the function which increases/deceases the timer.
Using

```
if ($('logoutstatus:contains("00:09:57")').length > 0) {
   $('.logoutstatus').show();
}
```

you check once, when the document is loaded. Very small chance that the timer will exactly be at that value at that time.

I'm sure you are using a function to change the content of `logoutstatus`. When you changed it, check the content, and whether the stopping time has been reached.

Comment: Is there a way to check the time continuously?

Comment: How are you setting the time in the div in the first place? Just place the check in that function.